# C#: Incremental string/var Names during While Loop

Tags: c#

first time posting here.  I'm looking to use a while loop to define several strings/vars.  This code gives an idea of what I'm looking for...

```
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 4)
    {
    string cmd1 = "Command 1";
    var num1 = 1;
    i++
    }
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get a while loop to somehow output...

```
string cmd1 = "Command 1";
var num1 = 1;
string cmd2 = "Command 2";
var num2 = 2;
string cmd3 = "Command 3";
var num3 = 3;
string cmd4 = "Command 4";
var num4 = 4;
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have any repeating values, you could use `Dictionary` in C#

```
var nums = new Dictionary<int, string>();

var i = 1;
while(i <= 4)
{
    nums.Add(i, $"Command {i}");
    i++;
}

foreach(var item in nums)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} - {item.Value}");
}
```

Comment: Also be noted that the console writing syntax works in c#6

Answer (score 1):

One liner :)

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 4).ToList().ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("Command " + i));
```

Make sure to add this in `using` section.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
```